# Text Selection duplicated only on android [Flutter]

Tags: android, flutter, textfield

On my flutter app When I select some text inside text field open a duplicated textSelection options, how can I fix to show only once?
this happens only on android
[image]

This is my code I created a textfield class and add some properties. but I facing this issue

```
`class _MyTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  const _MyTextField();

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyTextFieldState();
}

class _MyTextFieldState extends State<_MyTextField> {
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      enabled: true,
      maxLines: 3,
      minLines: 1,
      focusNode: _focusNode,
      controller: _controller,
      cursorColor: Colors.green,
      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
        ),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
        ),
        suffixIcon: IconButton(
          color: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () => {},
          icon: const Icon(Icons.post_add),
        ),
        hintText: 'hint text',
        hintStyle: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(
         15.0,
        ),
      ),
      onSubmitted: (text) => {},
    );
  }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in Flutter on Android, when you pick text, you might see two sets of options for copying or selecting the text. This happens because of how the system and the app work together.

To solve this, you can change your code a bit. There's a part where you set up the text field. If you use a special part called 'buildCounter' and put in an empty box, it can help to get rid of the extra set of options when you pick text.

```
class _MyTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  const _MyTextField();

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyTextFieldState();
}

class _MyTextFieldState extends State<_MyTextField> {
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      enabled: true,
      maxLines: 3,
      minLines: 1,
      focusNode: _focusNode,
      controller: _controller,
      cursorColor: Colors.green,
      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
        ),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
        ),
        suffixIcon: IconButton(
          color: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () => {},
          icon: const Icon(Icons.post_add),
        ),
        hintText: 'hint text',
        hintStyle: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(
         15.0,
        ),
      ),
      onSubmitted: (text) => {},
      // Disable default text selection handles
      buildCounter: (BuildContext context, { int? currentLength, int? maxLength, bool? isFocused }) => Container(),
    );
  }
}
```